# Neat solution for centered titlepage in twoside document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I use twoside in my document, and was foolish enough to think that

```
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
%Text
\end{titlepage}
```

would give me a titlepage which is centered in the ordinary fashion, i.e. as it would be in a oneside document. It is not, is there a nice solution to get this done nevertheless? As well as for the abstract and contents page?

The following is the relevant part from my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
%Much nice title
\end{titlepage}
%Nice text and stuff
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Maybe I did not phrase it clearly, but I only want to change this for the specific titlepage/contents/abstract pages, and this changes the whole document.

Comment: The default settings assume you want a double-page spread to look reasonable and so adjust the margins. If you want symmetry, use `geometry` and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Additionally, load package `showframe`. The title page, the contents page, the abstract page are all part of *one* document, and hence should all follow the same type area.  So what you experience, is the common way of typesetting. What you want is something *non-default* (*strange*).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the adjustment for a double-page spread, you can set the horizontal margin ratio to `1:1` with `geometry`, for example, and this will also get you an A4 layout, which you don't have at the moment, probably.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  Much nice title
\end{titlepage}
Nice text and stuff
\end{document}
```

If you only want to change the layout temporarily, use

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\savegeometry{mygeom}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{hmarginratio=1:1}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  Much nice title
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry{mygeom}
Nice text and stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase it clearly, but I only want to change this for the specific titlepage/contents/abstract pages, and this changes the whole document.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Please see edit. Or use `\newgeometry`. But this makes more sense, I think, for what you (now) describe.

Comment: The thing is that the hmargin command changes the margins of the document, which I don't want. Can it be done without changing the margins at all?

Comment: By default, you are using US letter layout on A4 paper. Geometry uses A4 layout when you specify A4. If you really want US letter layout, you can tell `geometry` to use US letter layout and A4 paper, but that makes no sense. Also, running it with `pass, verbose`, you can take the settings from the console to get the defaults and then use those. But, again, it is not correct to use the default layout for A4.